# How to query SQlite with integer param in iOS using FMDB?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to query a row which has a string in a particular column. However, I am unable to get the desired result.

**Code:**

```
 [_database open];
FMResultSet *results = [_database executeQuery:@"select * from testNotes where notesid=%d",notesID];
NSString *notes=[results stringForColumn:@"notes"];

if ([_database hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [_database  lastErrorCode], [_database lastErrorMessage]);
}

[_database close];
```

I checked the data using sqlite browser. The value I'm sending is 13, and the data exists in the table.

When I use: `notesid=%d` the console says: (Here `FMResultsSet` is `nil`, `notes` is `nil` )

> DB Error 1: near "%": syntax error

I also tried by giving a space in between =  and %d

When I use: `notesid='%d'` the console says:(Here `FMResultsSet` is not `nil`, `notes` is `nil`)

> DB Error 25: bind or column index out of range

And When I use:   `notesid='?'` the console says

> DB Error 25: bind or column index out of range

And when I use:   `notesid=?` the app is crashed at the `obj = va_arg(args, id);` in `FMDatabse.m` file

I also tried this:

```
[_database executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from testNotes where notesid='%d'",notesID]];
```

What is the proper way to query a row based on integer value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeQuery` expects all arguments to be Objective-C objects. However, `notesID` is an integer and thus not an object. In order to fix this, you'll need to wrap `notesID` in an `NSNumber` object like this:

```
FMResultSet *results = [_database executeQuery:@"select * from testNotes where notesid=?", @(notesID)];
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it still says bind or column index out of range.

Comment: Is there a way to use execute query without using while loop and doing [result next] ?

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.Mage suggests, I need to wrap the int value in NSNumber. And also , I need to add

```
  while([results next]) {
    notes = [results stringForColumn:@"notes"];
}
```

Without this while loop, I couldnt get the required result.

Now the working code will be:

```
 [_database open];
FMResultSet *results = [_database executeQuery:@"select * from testNotes where notesid= ?",@(notesID)];
NSString *notes;
while([results next]) {
    notes = [results stringForColumn:@"notes"];
}
if ([_database hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [_database  lastErrorCode], [_database lastErrorMessage]);
}

[_database close];
```